DFS search sibling node in specific condition else search children node
I have to do a DFS to search a tree, the DFS will first generate a result by the value of the node. The function check_for_three_kind_of_response is a function that checks if a question is related to a sentence. The result would be three responses, -1 means the sentence is not related to the question, 0 means the sentence is related to the question but the sentence can't help to answer the question, and last, return the answer(text) if the sentence can answer the question. If the result is -1 the DFS should search the sibling node, when the result is 0, the DFS should search the children node. Also, when the result is -1 but doesn't have a sibling node, it should also search its children node. At last, if the result is text, it should just return the text.
This is what I have tried, however, I was stuck in the condition when the result equals -1. Also, my tree is not a binary tree, its children are listed.
#                 Head
#                  |
#                Body
#                /  \
#      paragraph1       paragraph2
#       /   \             /  \  
# Sentence Sentence Sentence Sentence

This is what the tree looks like, the DFS first searches the head and returns -1 if it's not related to the question. Then, since the head doesn't have a siblings node, so it goes to its children node, which is the body. If it still returns -1, it would search its children node paragraph 1 since it didn't have a siblings node. When paragraph1 returns -1 in the function, it would jump to paragraph2. If it returns 0 it will go down to sentence. In a sentence, if the first one returns 0 it will search the next sentence while -1 will do the same thing. If all sentences return -1, the DFS should stop or otherwise go back to paragraph 2 to do the same routine again.
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value, parent = None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

def dfs(node, question):
    result = check_for_three_kind_of_response(question, node.value)
    # Check if the search function returns 0, -1, or text
    if result == "-1":
        return "-1"
    elif result != "0":
        return result
    for c in node.children:
        result = dfs(c, question)
        if result != "-1":
            return result
    return "-1"


What should happen if a node has 3 children, and we have already visited two children, and for the third child we get "-1"? This third child has two siblings. So according to the rule "If the result is -1 the DFS should search the sibling node", we should now search the sibling node. Which node is that sibling? We have already visited the two siblings of this node...

In that case, it should return to the parent node and go through its next node and its children. I am also thinking of stopping when it happens, so the result could be not find or no answer.

OK, so it seems you are not yet sure what you want to happen. I propose you first determine that. What should happen if for the three children the returned value from the recursive call is 0, -1 and the word? Or when it is 0, -1, 0? Or -1, -1, 0? What should be returned for the current node? The rules are not clear to me. Could you also edit your question and add a few, non-trivial examples of trees and what you expect as output for them?

When it's at the bottom of the tree the search will keep continue until it returns the text. Otherwise, if the node has children, it would search its children when returns 0, search siblings when returns -1, and stop when it's a text. I have added some examples, thanks a lot!
